# New File Uploading causing Edit Event

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, event-receivers, 2019

I have a document library that does not have any required fields, and needs not check-out before editing, saving only major versions. One of the users created an alert on the document library to inform her only when other users has modified files on the document library. She went on testing by uploading a brand new document, and found that the alert was triggered.

I tested with the same action in Modern Experience, and looked into the "EventCache" table in the content DB. There are more than one action logged on the upload action (one event type "4097" (Add item), one event type "8194" (Metadata update)). It seems the alert is triggered by the "8194" event.

I tested again in Classic Experience. Only one "4097" is created.

In another test to upload by file explorer, one "4097" followed by two "8194" is observed.

This inconsistent behavior confuses users and makes the out-of-the-box alert not usable. Is it a configuration problem or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is confusing, and seemingly inconsistent and yes, OOB alerts are terrible.

But that's the way SharePoint works, and there isn't much you can do about it. I'm surprised you didn't see an update event triggered in Classic - I know ItemUpdated event receivers will trigger when a document is uploaded in classic.

There **is** required metadata on documents - FileName, Created, CreatedBy, etc., are all updated subsequent to the file add, and this is the reason behind the dual events.

Comment: Thanks for your help Derek. In fact, we have tried the alerts in other SharePoint versions like SPO, SP2013, SP2010 and SP2016. All these versions have the alerts working as expected, which is why I wonder if it is a special case in SP2019. I know there is an update event triggered on new document upload, but I thought they will use some other event type for "System Updates", especially when no user input for the metadata is required...